# He makes $3$ products for his shop: large bowls, small bowls, and pots

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

> He makes $3$ products for his shop: large bowls, small bowls, and pots. Each large bowl uses $3$ pounds of clay and $6$ fluid ounces of glaze. Each small bowl uses $2$ pounds of clay and $6$ fluid ounces of glaze. Each pot requires $4$ pounds of clay and $2$ fluid ounces of glaze.
>
> He must use up $72$ pounds of old clay and $108$ fluid ounces of old glaze and can order more if necessary.
>
> If he can make a large bowl in $5$ hours, a small bowl in $6$ hours, and a pot in $4$ hours, determine how many of each he should make to minimize his time and what the minimum time will be.

So this is a linear optimization problem and I'm trying to set up the constraints first.

What answer did folks get on this?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo, could you please list the constraints and equations to work from for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are three products: So lets have

Large bowl = $x_{1}$

Small bowl = $x_{2}$

Pot = $x_{3}$

The objective function is:

min $5x_{1}+6x_{2}+4x_{3}$

Subjected to the constraints:

$3x_{1}+2x_{2}+4x_{3} \geq 72$

$6x_{1}+6x_{2}+2x_{3} \geq 108$

$x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3} \geq 0$

Comment: did you get 16, zero and 6 as the answer?

Comment: Yes! Also, you can use simplex online solver to verify your answer.